# Problem scripts in bash linux to check if files exist

Tags: linux, bash, testing, grep

I want to ask you for help with this problem, I have this script to detect files (I'm learning), but it doesn't detect the files and I can't see the error.
Can you guide me?
Thank you!

Folder where the script is located and executed:

```
home/jlia/scripts
```

Folder where the files are located:

```
home/jlia/data 
Contains:
        jane_contact_07292018.csv
        jane_profile_07272018.doc
        list.txt

list.txt 
        001 jane /data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
        002 kwood /data/kwood_profile_04022017.doc
        003 pchow /data/pcwow_profile_11042019.doc
        004 janez /data/janez_ptofile_11042019.doc
        005 jane /data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg
        006 kwood /data/kwood_pic_04032017.jpg
        007 pchow /data/pcwow_pic_05162019.jpg
        008 jane /data/jane_contact_07292018.csv
        009 kwood /data/kwood_contact_04042017.csv
        010 pchow /data/pchow_contact_05172019.csv
```

```
#!/bin/env bash

archivos=$(grep "/jane_" ../data/list.txt | cut -d' ' -f 3);
for file2 in $archivos;
do
    if [ -e "..${file2}" ];then
        echo "exist ..${file2}"; else
        echo "not existe ..${file2}";
    fi
done
```

Result:

```
not existe ../data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
not existe ../data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg
not existe ../data/jane_contact_07292018.csv
```

In the home/jlia/data folder there is a text file and others, with the script I extract with grep the location of the files that I must verify if they exist and return "exist" as a result
Problem, it doesn't detect the files that exist in the script but when executing it independently [ -e "Expression" ] it detects it.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but as a rule, it's error-prone to use `for` in this context; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: As for what _would_ constitute an answer to the question, we'd need to know where the files exist _relative to the current working directory that's active when you run the script_; that's different from the directory where the script itself is located. There's also potential for your data file to be in DOS format, which would have each filename have an invisible carriage-return character on its end; if the filenames don't have such a character, then it will of course not find them.

Comment: To detect that, you can run `bash -x yourscript`. Also, think about `$PWD/..${file2}` everywhere you currently write `..${file2}` so your logs show the full path where the files are searched for.

Comment: Particularly since you are learning, see the "Before asking about problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" sections of the ['bash' tag wiki - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find common problems in your code.  The problem reports include links to detailed information about the problems and how to fix them.

Comment: `-e "..${file2}"` looks very suspious. Don't you want `-e "../${file2}"`? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't seem to jive between your script and your messaging.

If the files weren't where they should be, for the script to report correctly, then the setting of **archivos** using the grep and relative reference would fail!!!

The fact that archivos was correctly set with valid path values from list.txt, the logic should have worked.

I am unable to reproduce your results, even using the script and creating demo directory and dummy files.

My version of the script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ${HOME}/scripts

if [ ! -s ../data/list.txt ]
then
    printf "\n WARNING:  Creating DEMO Data ...\n"
    mkdir ../data
    cat >"../data/list.txt" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
001 jane /data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
002 kwood /data/kwood_profile_04022017.doc
003 pchow /data/pcwow_profile_11042019.doc
004 janez /data/janez_ptofile_11042019.doc
005 jane /data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg
006 kwood /data/kwood_pic_04032017.jpg
007 pchow /data/pcwow_pic_05162019.jpg
008 jane /data/jane_contact_07292018.csv
009 kwood /data/kwood_contact_04042017.csv
010 pchow /data/pchow_contact_05172019.csv
EnDoFiNpUt

    if [ ! -s ../data/jane_contact_07292018.csv ]
    then
        printf "\n WARNING:  "
        echo "Dummy Content CREATED - jane_contact_07292018.csv" | tee ../data/jane_contact_07292018.csv
    fi

    if [ ! -s ../data/jane_profile_07272018.doc ]
    then
        printf "\n WARNING:  "
        echo "Dummy Content CREATED - jane_profile_07272018.doc" | tee ../data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
    fi
    echo ""
fi

archivos=$(grep "/jane_" ../data/list.txt | cut -d' ' -f 3) ;

for file2 in $archivos
do
    if [ -e "..${file2}" ]
    then
        echo "exist ..${file2}"
    else
        echo "not existe ..${file2}"
    fi
done
```

The output generated is this:

```
 WARNING:  Creating DEMO Data ...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘../data’: File exists

 WARNING:  Dummy Content CREATED - jane_contact_07292018.csv

 WARNING:  Dummy Content CREATED - jane_profile_07272018.doc

exist ../data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
not existe ../data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg
exist ../data/jane_contact_07292018.csv
```

Comment: Since we're trying to teach good practices, think about `printf '%b\n' '\n WARNING:   \c'` instead of the `echo -e`; that way the script will work even if bash is compiled or run with the xpg_echo flag, or if the code is reused in a script run in a shell like dash where `echo -e` prints `-e` on output.